# splitTools/create_folds setting random seed and repetition

Tags: r, cross-validation

If I set m_rep to 5  with 10 fold cross validation for  `create_folds` function from `splitTools` and set seed to a number. Does this mean all the repetitions will have the same train and test sets?

```py
create_folds(data[[targetVariable]], k = 10, m_rep = 5, type = "stratified", shuffle = TRUE, seed = 42)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the random number generator is initialized, then the (multiple) folds are being generated. The answer to your question is thus "no", which I guess makes sense.